# Slick Carousel & AngularJS Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

**Issue: Multiple dots and images (from last object) appearing after switch Object in Ng-repeat to different object**

Loading objects via http post into a div to display information but last object loaded still holds space (dots) in carousel.

Images as reference:

[image]

[image]

Related code:

```
 <slick autoplay="true" dots="true" infinite="true" autoplayspeed="500" fade="true" init-onload="true" data="currentProduct">
                                    <div ng-repeat="image in currentProduct.Images track by image.Id">
                                        <img src="http://cdnll.mysite.com/images/1000/{{image.ImageName}}.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
                                        <span>{{image.Id}}</span>
                                    </div>
                               </slick>


 $scope.displayDetails = function (product, scroll) {
    if ($scope.currentProduct != null)
        $scope.currentProduct.Images = [];
    if ($scope.showDetails) {
        $anchorScroll();
    }
    $scope.showDetails = true;
    $scope.currentProduct = product;
    $scope.lastScroll = scroll;
}
```

Directive reference: 
https://github.com/devmark/angular-slick-carousel

```
if (scope.initOnload) {
              isInitialized = false;
              return scope.$watch('data', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                  if (newVal != null) {
                      if (isInitialized) {
                          destroySlick();
                          // this does happen!! every new instance of currentProduct
                      }
                      initializeSlick();
                      return isInitialized = true;
                  }
              });
          } else {
              return initializeSlick();
          }

 destroySlick = function () {
              return $timeout(function () {
                  var slider;
                  slider = $(element);
                  slider.slick('unslick');
                  slider.find('.slick-list').remove();
                  return slider;
              });
          };
```

Reference for slick carousel: 
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an issue with the css. make sure you have the right css for the version of slick you are using.